# Timer Callback in C++

Tags: c++

I need to call a function asynchronously for every x miliseconds. I am coding in C++, Linux environment. What functions could I call to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Look into the Boost timers.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems that I need to call  io_service::run() for the callback function to be called. Is there anyway I could avoid this as I just need the callback function to be called after x miliseconds and needing me to call io_service::run() would need me to invoke it after a certain period of time, which defeat the purpose of using the timer callback function. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing one simple thing: you need to provide a thread on which to call the timer. This is what io_service::run() is for. You can create a dedicated thread for this if you want. If you're in a special environment (e.g. some widget toolkit with a message loop, you need to tell us that).

Comment: That "thread to run io_service::run()" call looks like this: boost::thread timerThread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));